# Replacing spaces with dots, only between numbers in perl

Tags: regex, perl

I have a string:

```
0297  239391/058/04       30 07.20 08:45:45
```

I would like to come out with regex that finds only the spaces between two numbers and replacing them with dots.

Expected output:

```
 0297  239391/058/04       30.07.20.08:45:45
```

I found ways to do this in other languages but could not find a solution in perl.

Comment: What is the expected output for that example?

Answer (score 3):

The naïve attempt might be

```perl
s/(\d) (\d)/$1.$2/g
```

But that would fail for `1 2 3`. The `2` would have to be matched twice.

---

On the other extreme, we can use a lookbehind and a lookahead.

```perl
s/(?<=\d) (?=\d)/./g
```

That works, but it's relatively expensive.

---

The following compromise is better:

```perl
s/\d\K (?=\d)/./g
```

(Technically, `s/ /./g` would be sufficient for your example.)

Comment: I tried s/ /./g an the beginning but the output was not what I was looking for. In the end I found a way around it with: ~s/(\d{2})\s(\d{2})\./$1.$2./g. and if($string=~m/(\d{2})(\s)(\d{2})(\s)(\d{2})/g) {
       $string=~s/(\d{2})\s(\d{2})\s(\d{2})\s/$1.$2.$3 /g
    };  for 3 charakters

Comment: Thanks so much for you answers, I ll try to make it with lookbehind and lookahead later, never tried it in REGEX before, but seems like useful solution